# Can you not use And[] inside a Select[]?

Tags: filtering

I have a list of lists of integers that are each sorted numerically. Here is a sample of it: `{{2, 8, 9}, {3, 7, 9}, {4, 6, 9}, ...}`. I wish to only pick out members which meet the following criteria:

1. No two elements within it are consecutive:`ContainsNone[Union@Differences[#], {1}] &`
2. The length of the list is itself a member of the list:`ContainsAny[#, {Length@#}] &]`

Each test independently works fine:

```
In=Select[mylist, ContainsNone[Union@Differences[#], {1}] &]
Out={{3, 7, 9}, {4, 6, 9}, {1, 3, 6, 9}, {1, 4, 6, 8}}

In=Select[mylist, ContainsAny[#, {Length@#}] &]
Out={{3, 7, 9}, {1, 4, 5, 9}, {1, 4, 6, 8}, {2, 4, 5, 8}, {2, 4, 6, 7}, {3, 4, 5, 7}, {1, 2, 3, 5, 8}, {1, 2, 4, 5, 7}, {1, 3, 4, 5, 6}}
```

However when I attempt to use an `And[]` function with `Select[]` to only pick out lists that meet both criteria I am presented with an empty result when clearly at least `{3,7,9}` meets both criteria:

```
In=Select[mylist,And[ContainsNone[Union@Differences[#], {1}] &,ContainsAny[#, {Length@#}] &]]
Out={}
```

Is it that `And[]` is not working as I intend it inside this `Select[]` function? Surely if `Select[]` passes each member one by one, the `And[]` will return True when it gets to `{3,7,9}`, no? Or is it some other reason? I know I can just output each and do an `Intersection[]` but I just want to figure out how to use Select to do what I intend.

Comment: Use `myList // Select[And[pred1, pred2, ...] /* Through]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
list = {{2, 8, 9}, {3, 7, 9}, {4, 6, 9}};

Select[list, 
 ContainsNone[Union @ Differences[#], {1}] && 
   ContainsAny[#, {Length @ #}] &]
```

{{3, 7, 9}}

Or, if you want the `And`:

```
Select[list, 
 And[ContainsNone[Union@Differences[#], {1}], 
   ContainsAny[#, {Length@#}]] &]
```

{{3, 7, 9}}

Comment: So I understand correctly, it was me treating each test as a separate function that was causing the issue? I see here you're merging them both into one function?

Comment: Yes, one could say so

Comment: Do you know what it is about Select's innerworkings that would reject an And[] evaluation of two different functions onto one list member?

Comment: The predicate you give to `Select` must evaluate to either `True` or `False`. Your only mistake was, that  you duplicated the `&` and put the `]` in the wrong positions (at the end)